# Django add to cart as a guest without logging in

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a ecom website project and I follow Dennis Ivy's course about cart functionality. I want to add to cart whether the person is logged in or not. I place my code down below, where products are added to the cart as a order when you're logged in and everything's fine but when user is not logged in nothing happen even though I created the device key inside cookies.

models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email          = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name     = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name      = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    username       = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, unique=False, blank=True)
    is_active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True



class Guest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    device = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.name:
            name = self.name
        else:
            name = self.device
        return str(name)

class Order(models.Model):
    klient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    gosc = models.ForeignKey(Guest, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    data_zamowienia = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    dostarczona = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    produkt = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ilosc = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    data_dodania = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def order_set(self):
        pass
```

views:

```
def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    try:
        user = request.user
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(klient=user, produkt=product, dostarczona=False)
    except:
        device = request.COOKIES['device']
        customer, created = Guest.objects.get_or_create(device=device)
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(gosc=customer, produkt=product, dostarczona=False)


    if action == 'add':
        order.ilosc = (order.ilosc + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        order.ilosc = (order.ilosc - 1)

    order.save()

    if order.ilosc <= 0:
        order.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

Comment: The try-except block in your view will only execute the code below the except on an exception. The `Order.objects.get_or_create(klient=user, produkt=product, dostarczona=False)` query won't produce an exception on an empty response. It will just return an empty response. I think it would be better to put that into an if-else block instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i already tried to make it inside if-else statement(if request.user or request.user.customer) and its still the same. When I wanted to print device in the console it prints when I’m logged in so inside view it reads device key properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick test with the following view.

```
def myview(request):
    print(request.user)
    return HttpResponse("hello")
```

In an unauthenticated session, request.user isn't empty or `None` by the looks of it.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 09, 2021 - 21:45:29
Django version 3.1.5, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
AnonymousUser
[09/Jan/2021 21:45:33] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5
```

So if you're just doing a truthy check on `request.user` it's always going to be true.

You could perhaps do the following:

```
def myview(request):

    if request.user != 'AnonymousUser':
        # insert logged in user code here
    else: 
        # insert your device related code here
```

Comment: Grizzle is right, that's the way I do it:

`if request.user != 'AnonymousUser':`